# Android Action Bar - With Tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am trying to create a tab action bar on android but I seem to face problems when following tutorials. They usually will have resources which are not shown of which I am also not too sure what are they an causing me not being able to compile the project like in the tutorial. can someone kindly help me out with this. thanks.

Comment: which version of Android are you using? There is an ActionBar class in later versions of Android

Comment: @Suchi i am running it on a android 3.0 tablet. i referred to a tutorial on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMu8XhxUBl8&feature=relmfu but i am having run time exceptions.

Answer (score 10):

[Here is another sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Honeycomb/FeedFragments), covered in one of my books, that demonstrates tabs in the action bar, among other features.

Answer (score 2):

Android has many examples in their APIDemos; `ActionBarTabs` is one of them.

Comment: yeah, i know about that, i tried running it on my tablet but it doesn't seem to work. the thing is that the codes in it have alot of other examples which makes things harder for me to see.

Comment: For reference, the API Demo for ActionBarTabs, is located at ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/ActionBarTabs. I found the FragmentTabs demo also useful – it's in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's important that you set "Theme.Holo" has your application main theme at the Android Manifest. Any Holo theme will do (Theme.Holo.Light, Theme.Holo.foo.bar)

Your  tag has to be something like this

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
```